# Wait for function finish

Tags: typescript

I have structure like:

```
function1 ()
{
A;
function2(){};
B;
}
```

How can i force function2 return result then run B? it always A->B->function2

Appreciate any comments.
Paxton.

Comment: You are not calling `function2` anywhere, just defining it.

Comment: function1 ()
{
A;
function2(){B;};

}

Comment: function 2 in a loop so if i put B in function2 so B will reply so may times? how can i avoid that. Thanks you guys for quick reply

Comment: @Paxton.Huynh this sounds like a new question. Open another one with more code, including your loop. Ideally so anyone can run it.

Comment: your code structure isn't very clear... if you want to get the result of `function2()` then call that in `function1()`, and what exactly is `B` and `A` returning are they methods of the each respective function, you will have to look into local scope if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is answer, if the function is not async.

```js
function a() {
  console.log('a');
  function b() {
    console.log('b');
  }
  b();
}
a();
```

Comment: function 2 in a loop so if i put B in function2 so B will reply so may times? how can i avoid that. Thanks you guys for quick reply

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack
but, it is so short.
https://medium.com/@gaurav.pandvia/understanding-javascript-function-executions-tasks-event-loop-call-stack-more-part-1-5683dea1f5ec

I think you need to know call stack. :)